# SAS Merge two dataset with same variable name

Tags: sas

I have the following program which merge two observations, but with same column name (variable), I want to know why in the merge result column A get dropped?

```
data three;
     merge one(in=a) two;
     by ID;     
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get a note in the log telling you why.

```
WARNING: The variable a exists on an input data set and is also set by an I/O statement 
         option.  The variable will not be included on any output data set and unexpected
         results can occur.
```

Don't use the `IN=` dataset option if you don't need it. Or make sure not to use a name that is already a variable in the dataset.

```
data three;
  merge one(in=in1) two;
  by ID;
  if in1;
run;
```